# How do I return a true when checking against 4 values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement that has to allow for 4 parameter values and I am having trouble getting the syntax correct.

I have tested the 2 parts of the OR statement below separately and these return a true and false respectively but what I want is because the first argument returned a true for the do something to occur.

```js
var d = 4;
var t = 2;
if ( (d >= 3.5 && d < 6) || (t >= 3.5 && t < 6) ){
   console.log('true'); // do something
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

I expect the if statement to be TRUE because the first part of the OR statement is correct and any code within to run.

UPDATE-------------------------------------------

Still getting issues, I have expanded the sample code to include what I am seeing

```js
var dlG = "2";
var dl  = "3.5";


if(parseFloat(dlG) < 3.5){
    console.log("DLG Red");
}else if ( parseFloat(dlG) >= 3.5 && parseFloat(dlG) < 6 ){
    console.log("DLG Purple");
}else if (parseFloat(dlG) >= 6){
    console.log("DLG Green");     
}

if(parseFloat(dl) < 3.5){
    console.log("dl Red");
}else if ( parseFloat(dl) >= 3.5 && parseFloat(dl) < 6 ){
    console.log("dl Purple");
}else if (parseFloat(dl) >= 6){
    console.log("dl Green");    
}

if((parseFloat(dl) < 3.5) || (parseFloat(dlG) < 3.5)){
    console.log("Both Red");
}else if ((parseFloat(dl) >= 3.5 && parseFloat(dl) < 6 ) || (parseFloat(dlG) >= 3.5 && parseFloat(dlG) < 6 )){
    console.log("Both Purple");
}else if ((parseFloat(dl) >= 6) || (parseFloat(dlG) >= 6)){
    console.log("Both Green");      
}
```

Essentially the first and second **if** statements work independently but I wanted to combine them with an OR statement in the 3rd if statement where I would expect to see 'Both Purple' in the console log but I see 'Both Red'.

Any ideas what I need to change?

Comment: you code works exactly as you described. Given your snippet, //do something will get executed.

Comment: this is working for me at the moment

Comment: Thanks for your comments, to simplify the code on StackOverflow I declared the variables, but these are actually produced from a much larger piece of code on my site. I was foolish as going back to my code showed the variables were strings and I was comparing against a number. I will fix my code and it should work as per the snippet above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle, on my example above the first if statement returned TRUE on certain criteria. On the second if statement the middle part (the first else if) returned TRUE on certain criteria.

I could not work out while the 3rd if statement was not working as expect but it was because the first and second parts both were returning TRUE.

Approaching the problem (in my larger code set) without using the if statements (and else parts) but using a different methodology has resolved the issue.

Thank you Randy and Colin for your help